# Prevent Visual Studio from Overriding Poject internal SPList

Tags: 2013, javascript, deployment, sharepoint-hosted-app, splist

Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from Overriding Poject internal SPList?

And how can I reuse a already created List inside an App? The Lists is not accessible after a new deployment of the app. I think it is because of the new App URL.

I need help cause I dont want to input all of the data once more...